# How to upload video to Firebase Storage in background - swift - Programmatically

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm sending a video and the thumbnail Image from the client to `Firebase Storage` and I save the respective urls in `Firestore` using this procedure:

```
fileprivate func sendVideoToDatabase(urlVideo : URL){
    ProgressHUD.showProgress(0.0, interaction: true)
    
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    
    let videoName = UUID().uuidString
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("Videos").child("\(videoName).mp4")
    
    let storageThumbnailsRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("thumbnails")
    
    storageRef.putFile(from: urlVideo, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if let error = error{
            print("failed upload video \(error.localizedDescription)")
            ProgressHUD.showFailed()
            return
        }
        
        ProgressHUD.showProgress(0.1, interaction: true)
        storageRef.downloadURL { (urlVideo, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                ProgressHUD.showFailed()
                return
            }
            
            ProgressHUD.showProgress(0.2, interaction: true)
            
            let firestoreMoments = Firestore.firestore().collection("Moments").document(uid).collection("Moments")
            
            ProgressHUD.showProgress(0.3, interaction: true)
            
            self.getImageFromVideo(url: urlVideo!, at: 1) { (imageRetrieved) in
                let imageID = "\(UUID().uuidString).jpg"
                guard let imageData = imageRetrieved?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.35) else { return }
                
                ProgressHUD.showProgress(0.4, interaction: true)
                
                storageThumbnailsRef.child(imageID).putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                    
                    ProgressHUD.showProgress(0.5, interaction: true)
                    if let err = error{
                        print("impossible to add a thumbnail image: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                        ProgressHUD.showFailed()
                        return
                    }
                    
                    ProgressHUD.showProgress(0.6, interaction: true)
                    
                    storageThumbnailsRef.child(imageID).downloadURL { (url, err) in
                        if let err = err{
                            print("impossible to download image: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                            ProgressHUD.showFailed()
                            return
                        }
                        ProgressHUD.showProgress(0.7, interaction: true)
                        
                        guard let thumbnailUrl = url?.absoluteString else { return }
                        
                        let docRef = firestoreMoments.document()
                        
                        ProgressHUD.showProgress(0.8, interaction: true)
                        
                        docRef.setData(["type" : "video",
                                        "uid": uid,
                                        "videoUrl" : urlVideo!.absoluteString,
                        ]) { (error) in
                            if let error = error{
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                                ProgressHUD.showFailed()
                                return
                            }
                            ProgressHUD.showProgress(1, interaction: true)
                            
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
                                ProgressHUD.dismiss()
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Meanwhile I show a `progressHUD` that prevents any user interaction from the client side until the uploading process is complete. The problem is that it takes a lot of time for a video of decent size (20MB).

I was wondering is there a way to implement an uploading process that goes on in the server side or background? so that the client can go on and perform other tasks meanwhile?

Comment: The only reason the UI is frozen until the task completes is because you’ve made it that way. There’s nothing stopping you from uploading the file and allowing the user to move on. The only problem is that if the upload fails then what do you do? What if the user has navigated far away?

Comment: Exactly! I made the UI blocking purposefully because if the upload fails and “ the user has navigated far away” he can’t access the video no more for re trying to upload it, or at least, to save it in local videos. How can I be sure that the video is gonna be uploaded even in background so that I can dismiss the UI without caring

Comment: Unfortunately you can never be sure because the user may terminate the app or lose connection, two things you can do nothing about. The best you can do is create a recursive function that automatically retries on failure.

Comment: I am with @bxod here. Firebase is pretty much an asynchronous API - it does stuff in the background enabling the user to go do other tasks. Take the iOS/macOS mail.app as an example; while the app is downloading a bunch of new emails, the user can continue to use the app. If the downloading is interrupted it tells the user and/or tries again. It would not be difficult to present a dialog when the upload fails to prompt the user to either Try Again or to Cancel the upload.

Comment: makes sense, thank you @Jay !